# Convert php to json in following format

Tags: php, json

I am new to **`PHP`** and **`JSON`**.
I want to convert my php array to json in the following format

my json file should look like following.

```
[
  {
    "title": "All Day Event",
    "start": "2015-02-01"
  },
  {
    "title": "Long Event",
    "start": "2015-02-07",
    "end": "2015-02-10"
  },
  {
    "id": "999",
    "title": "Repeating Event",
    "start": "2015-02-09T16:00:00-05:00"
  },
  {
    "id": "999",
    "title": "Repeating Event",
    "start": "2015-02-16T16:00:00-05:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Conference",
    "start": "2015-02-11",
    "end": "2015-02-13"
  },
  {
    "title": "Meeting",
    "start": "2015-02-12",
    "end": "2015-02-12"
  },
  {
    "title": "Lunch",
    "start": "2015-02-12T12:00:00-05:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Meeting",
    "start": "2015-02-12"
  },
  {
    "title": "Happy Hour",
    "start": "2015-02-12T17:30:00-05:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Dinner",
    "start": "2015-02-12T20:00:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Birthday Party",
    "start": "2015-02-13T07:00:00-05:00"
  },
  {
    "title": "Click for Google",
    "url": "http://google.com/",
    "start": "2015-02-28"
  }
]
```

I have data in table, please tell me how can i form my php array so that it will get converted to above json file

Comment: Do you know how to get the data from your table?

Comment: `echo json_encode($yourArray);` ?!

Answer (score 0, accepted):

You can forge your JSON with [Simple JSON for PHP v3](https://github.com/AlexisTM/Simple-Json-PHP). It will also send the correct headers.

Here is a full example with a custom class

```
<?php
  // The only include you need
  include('../includes/json.php');

  class dataConstructor extends content {
    public function __construct($title, $start = false, $end = false, $id = false){
      $json = new json();
      $json->add('id', $id);
      $json->add('title', $title);
      $json->add('start', $start);
      $json->add('end', $end);
      $this->json = $json->make();
    }
    public function get(){
      return $this->json;
    }
  }

  $json = new json();

  //for ($results ...) // Grab data from bdd
  //...
  $data = new dataConstructor('All Day Event','2015-02-01');
  $json->add('data', $data->get(), false);
  //...
  $data = new dataConstructor('All Day Event', '2015-02-07', '2015-02-10');
  $json->add('data', $data->get(), false);
  //... 
  $data = new dataConstructor('Repeating Event', '2015-02-09T16:00:00-05:00', false, 999);
  $json->add('data', $data->get(), false);
  //}

  $json->send_array();
?>
```

It results in :

```
[
    {
        "id": false,
        "title": "All Day Event",
        "start": "2015-02-01",
        "end": false
    },
    {
        "id": false,
        "title": "All Day Event",
        "start": "2015-02-07",
        "end": "2015-02-10"
    },
    {
        "id": 999,
        "title": "Repeating Event",
        "start": "2015-02-09T16:00:00-05:00",
        "end": false
    }
]
```

Answer (score 0):

Your array format should be in this format that i am showing as an example:

```
$arr = array( 0=>array('title'=>All Day Event,'start'=>'2015-02-07','end'=>'2015-02-10'),1=>array('title'=>All Day Event,'start'=>'2015-02-07','end'=>'2015-02-10') )
```

Programmatic structure of the array example:

```
$arr[0]['title']='All Day Event';
$arr[0]['start']='2015-02-07';
$arr[0]['end']='2015-02-10';
$arr[1]['title']='All Day Event';
$arr[1]['start']='2015-02-07';
$arr[1]['end']='2015-02-10';
```

This was an example as per your question, you can dynamically assign the values in an loop using a counter.

Then `json_encode` the array

```
$json = json_encode($arr);
```